# Which keyboard can plug into an iPhone 5s?

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I have an iPhone 5s, the screen is broken and so I cannot get past the lock screen.

I have seen that you can plug a keyboard directly into the iPhone 5s to enter the lock screen pin code.

I cannot find a straight answer on which keyboard would work with this. I know the iPhone 5s has a lightning port, so I either want:

1. A keyboard which has a lightning cable.
2. An adapter to convert a USB keyboard cable to a Lightning port.

I cannot find any of #1, this is the closest thing I could find from Apple for #2, but it says it's for cameras:
https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD821AM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter

Does anyone know if that will work, or can make a recommendation?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are possible.

1) You can get for example the "Logitech Wired Keyboard for iPad with Lightning Connector" [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JXPGX04) or the "Griffin Wired Keyboard" [2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JXPGX04) with Lightning connector.

2) The Lightning to USB Camera Adapter will work for most, if not all, USB keyboards - even though it says it is intended for cameras.